# question about subtraction of two strings in c programming

Tags: c, string, subtraction

I have a question from an interview and need a little help:

What is `"abcd" - "xyz"`?

1. Address
2. Integer
3. The operation is illegal for the compiler
4. str
5. none of the above

I'm pretty sure its 4. Can someone tell me if it's true and what's the correct explanation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219092/discussion-on-question-by-adb-question-about-subtraction-of-two-strings-in-c-pro).

Answer (score 4):

Normally in C, the difference between two pointers is an integer of type `ptrdiff_t` representing the distance between the two objects pointed at. That's the interpretation which would apply here because a string literal is shorthand for an array of characters and, as with any array, using it in an expression causes the array to "decay" into a pointer to its first element.

However, `"abcd" - "xyz"` is Undefined Behaviour because subtraction of one pointer from another is only defined if the two pointers refer to objects in the same array. (Otherwise, the "distance between the two objects" is meaningless.)

The multiple choice provided doesn't list "Undefined Behaviour" as an option. Option 3 would not be correct unless you know something about the particular compiler referred to: since the standard does not define behaviour, a compiler is free to implement anything it sees fit. It could accept the expression and return a meaningless result, or it could generate an error message and terminate the compilation, or it could do anything else that seemed reasonable to the compiler writer.

So if I were asked this question, I'd go for answer 5 ("None of the above") and be prepared to explain my reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's take a sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str1[] = "abcd";
    char str2[] = "xyz";

    int x = str1 - str2;

    printf("Subtraction diff: %d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

You thinks that the program does subtracts two strings, right? But, No!

The program doesn't subtracts two strings, we've two `char[]` here. `x` holds the **memory address difference** between `str1[]` and `str2[]` for representation. This can be pretty much anything arbitrary. The aforementioned program will display `4`, i.e. space between the start of the first string and the start of the second one on your stack is 4 bytes.

---

**Related:** In C++, you could take the help of `auto` keyword in this example to let the compiler decide the appropriate type for the expression, similar to:

```
auto x = str1 - str2;
std::cout << x;
```

Answer (score -1):

`"abcd" - "xyz"` is always an integer (more specifically `ptrdiff_t`).

The operation always works in C/C++. The meaning of the result, however, will depend on the input strings. In most cases, the offset between two "random" strings is likely meaningless. Where it would be useful is the pointer at the end of the string minus the pointer at the start of the string. That gives you the length of the string.

```
char const * s = "abcd";
char const * e = s;
while(*e != '\0') ++e;
size_t const len = e - s;
```

That being said, I have dealt with strings in many different ways and a `ptrdiff_t` can be useful in many different circumstances. As long as you are in control of where the strings are, there may be a meaning that is perfectly valid for your specific case.

Comment: In your answer, you wrote: `"The operation is always valid in C/C++"` -- This statement is incorrect, at least for C (C++ is not relevant here). In this case, the behavior is undefined, because the pointers do not both point inside the same object. See the top-rated answer for further information. See [§6.5.6 ¶9 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p9) for the normative text.

Comment: Note that when the behavior is undefined, this means that the behavior of the entire program is undefined, not just the behavior of the `-` operation. In such a case, it does not seem appropriate to call the operation "valid".

Comment: I reworded that as "always works". It will always give you a difference between the two pointers.

Comment: The new wording is equally incorrect. The behavior of the entire program is [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Therefore, nothing is guaranteed to "work", at least as far as the ISO C standard is concerned. It may be true that it will "always work" on some [platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform), but this is not guaranteed to be the case on all platforms.

Comment: Even if it happens to work on your platform, it is generally recommended to avoid undefined behavior at all costs. Here is a nice example of things that can happen if you do not do that: [Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)

Comment: The type of the expression is `ptrdiff_t`, an integer type, but the **behavior is undefined** and the compiler should produce a warning, at least if instructed to be user friendly with `-Wall` or equivalent.

Comment: @chqrlie: In your previous comment, you wrote: `"The type of the expression is ptrdiff_t"` -- As far as I can tell, even that statement is incorrect, when the behavior is undefined. According to [§3.4.3 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3), the standard "imposes no requirements" on the behavior of the program. My interpretation is that the program could just as well behave as if the type of the expression were a pointer type instead of an integer type. However, I agree that it is highly unlikely that an implementation would actually do that.